# How to I make global.asax run when the URL has a dot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a website running on IIS 7.5 which I can only access using FTP. (So I won't be able to use IIS Manager.)

I want to reorganise the URL structure, so I've modified the Global.asax code to look for the old URLs and Response.Redirect them to their new location. This works great for some of the URLs but not all.

With some experimentation, I found that when the old URL has a dot (eg, http://example.com/hello.html) then my global.asax code doesn't run. If I remove the file extension part of the URL, the global.asax code runs fine.

Those URLs with .html etc on the end are already out there and I can't change them now.

What do I need to do please?

Comment: We'll need to see the code in your Global.asax to help, any chance you can provide it?

Comment: The code looks at Request.Url, does some transformations and ends with Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that IIS thinks your request for "/hello.html" is a static file and tries to serve it up directly without handing it off to your ASP.ENT application (before it gets to the routing in your Globals.asax file).

To change this behavior, you need to tell IIS to send these requests to your ASP.NET app instead of handling them itself.  You can do this in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name = "LetMeHandleMyOwnStaticContent" path ="/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersion4.0"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Note, this will make you handle ALL of the static files (be prepared to handle the .js files, .css files, .html files, .png files, etc.) through your app.  You can manipulate the path and verb to narrow down what you want to serve through your app.  You can add multiple filters by repeating the "add" element (just use a unique name for each path).